# Higher order function to apply many functions to one argument

Tags: higher-order-functions

I want the common name of a higher order function that applies a list of functions onto a single argument.

In this sense it is a converse of map.  `map` takes a function and a list of arguments and applies that function to the entire list.  In Python it might look like this

```
map = lambda fn, args: [fn(arg) for arg in args]
```

I'm thinking of the function that does the same but has the alternate argument as a list type

```
??? = lambda fns, arg: [fn(arg) for fn in fns]
```

I suspect that this function exists and has a common name.  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you describe is not the converse of `map`, but just `map` applied in another way. Consider, e.g.,

```
map(lambda f: f(2), [lambda x: x + 1, lambda x: x, lambda x: x * x])
```

which in effect applies three functions (plus 1, identity, and squaring) to the argument `2`. So what you wanted is just

```
alt_map = lambda x, fns: map(lambda f: f(x), fns)
```

which is still an ordinary map.