# FP (function programming): notation

Tags: functional-programming, notation

The language used here is [FP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_%28programming_language%29).

I don't understand the difference between the use of `<>` and `[]`.

For example:

```
2 : <3,4,5> -> 4
```

But

```
+ o [1,2] : <2,3> -> 5
```

Why is the first sequence written with `[]` instead of `<>` ?

Thanks!

Comment: What language in particular? Haskell? Functional languages don't necessarily share syntax.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(programming_language)

Comment: Ah. I honestly didn't know about that one. Thought you were using `FP` for the generic idea of functional programming. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is actually in the wiki link you provided. While `<...>` is used as notation for lists (e.g., `<3,4,5>` is a list with elements `3`, `4`, and `5`), `[...]` is just syntax for a functional that is already provided by FP. It is called *construction* and defined by

```
[f1, ..., fn]:x =  <f1:x, ..., fn:x>
```

If you are familiar with Haskell: it is similar to

```
map (\f -> f x) [f1, ..., fn] = [f1 x, ..., fn x]
```

that is to say, that `[...]` is some kind of map function, see also [Higher order function to apply many functions to one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758077/higher-order-function-to-apply-many-functions-to-one-argument).

In your specific examples

```
2:<3, 4, 5>
```

selects the second element of the given list, and `+ o [1, 2]:<2, 3>` can be "evaluated" as 
follows (where `o` is *function composition*):

```
+ o [1, 2]:<2, 3>  => (definition of composition)
+:([1, 2]:<2, 3>) => (definition of construction)
+:<1:<2, 3>, 2:<2, 3>> => (select list elements)
+:<2, 3> => (addition)
5
```